# Is there access a php script on a wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i have tried to load a flat panel write on PHP i put in a wordpress theme. 
for alone the script run great but i want run that on wordpress theme.

problem in them routing. for example:
site/wp-content/themes/admin/dashboard/
site/wp-content/themes/admin/dashboard/sprofile
site/wp-content/themes/admin/dashboard/rprofile

can not access above route.

i think this solve with .htaccess file but don't know how !?
is there any way?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wordpress you may want to create a shortcode for your script but, in case you don't want to, you can also use .htaccess with the rewrite module to redirect a url and  access your panel.

Here are two examples that I hope will help you:

[.htaccess rewrite examples](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

[Shortcode examples](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-shortcodes-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation correctly, you want to run a piece of PHP code which prints stuff inside the page as a feature in your WP theme. Not knowing the details, i can give you a couple of ideas:

1. If you need to **embed** that in an existing page (or s a new page itself), you need to create a template/template part and manage it trough wordpress's apis (which includes, as said, shipping it as a template part or a template itself, [See codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/))
2. If you need to create a new page with custom logic which is more suitable to be written as a plugin, consider adding a rewrite rule to a custom route (See [this section of the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and take a look at [this article](https://metabox.io/how-to-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress/))

Answer (score 0):

that is i want

when enter to
site/wp-content/themes/admin/dashboard/login

rewrite to

site/wp-content/themes/admin/dashboard/?url=login

> login not static

now i use this to htaccess but don't work :

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/bluetheme/dashboard/(.*)$ /subdirectory/wp-content/themes/bluetheme/dashboard?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't try cheating on WP, by smuggling your php file in some dir and trying to call it from there, by tweaking .htaccess file and similar. Look for system way to create custom WP page. I.e.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/